# Сколько длится блокировка входа на github?

Tags: github

Забыл свой пароль на github. Ввёл раз 10 неправильно. Вход был заблокирован с моего IP (пишут, что с вашего IP было слишком много попыток входа, теперь подождите и попробуйте ещё раз).

Сколько нужно подождать?

Comment: Насколько я знаю с каждым неудачным входом это время увеличивается